# Anonymous callback function in for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a function inside an async.waterfall that checks each id in an array if there is any entry in a mongodb with this id (using Mongoose). If the id already exists it's to be removed from the array. I wrote the following function:

```
    function(eventIds, callback) {
        // check for duplicates
        for (var i = 0; i < eventIds.length; i++) {
            var query = Party.find({
                fbEventId: eventIds[i]
            });
            query.exec(function(err, doc) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                if (doc) {
                    // remove i from array
                    console.log(doc);
                }
            });
        }
        callback(null, eventIds);
    }
```

This however gives a warning because a new function is constructed in a for loop.

If i create the function outside the for loop like below it gives an error: ReferenceError: err is not defined.

```
    function(eventIds, callback) {
        // check for duplicates
        function checkDuplicate(err, doc) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            if (doc) {
                    // remove i from array
                console.log(doc);
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < eventIds.length; i++) {
            var query = Party.find({
                fbEventId: eventIds[i]
            });
            query.exec(checkDuplicate(err, doc));
        }
        callback(null, eventIds);
    }
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: As a note, the `callback` will exec before all of the `checkDuplicate` calls execute / finish.  Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: No it's indeed not what I want, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function, not assigning a reference to it.

Your code

```
query.exec(query.exec(checkDuplicate(err, doc));
```

should be

```
query.exec(query.exec(checkDuplicate));
```